# Angular 2 POST request to the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, rest, service-worker

Здравстуйте. Делаю приложение для добавления новостей. При добавлении новости нужно обрабатывать отсутствие Интернета (новость отправляется на сервер при восстановлении связи). Как это реазизовать? Я читал что можно использовать Service Workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [такие события](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) y `window`, которые помогут вам отследить обрыв и восстановление соединения:

```js
window.addEventListener('offline', e => alert('offline'))
window.addEventListener('online', e => alert('online'))
```